# Rearrange single pictures in Photos?

Tags: macos, photos.app

How do you manually rearrange single pictures in Apple "Photos"? In iPhoto it was possible to select the picture, hold down the mouse button and move to another position in the album. Has that feature been deleted?

Answer (score 1):

The default views (**Moments**, **Collections**, **Years**), as well as all automatic albums (**All Photos**, **Selfies**, **Videos**…) are always sorted with the most recent at the bottom. This ordering cannot be changed.

However you can create Albums, throw your pictures in there, then rearrange them to your heart’s content.

To view your albums, press <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd>. You can also show the sidebar by pressing <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> <kbd>⌥ opt</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> (it will be shown by default in macOS 10.13 High Sierra). Either option will give you access to your albums. Once you open an album, simply drag-and-drop it wherever you like with the mouse.

This will not affect the default views and automatic albums.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63304/discussion-on-answer-by-phong-rearrange-single-pictures-in-photos).